# Window Calculations in SAQL

Tags: sql, einstein-analytics, einstein, saql, tableau-crm

I'm new to SAQL. I'm seeing a reference example where they are calculating three months ago: `sum(sum(A)) over ([-3..-3] partition by Manager_Name order by ('DATA_DT_Year', 'DATA_DT_Month')) as 'three_months_ago'`.

In the same way, if I want to calculate three months ago the previous year let us say if we are in August 2023, I want to calculate May, June & July of 2022.

I've implemented the following: `sum(sum(A)) over ([-15..-15] partition by Manager_Name order by ('DATA_DT_Year','DATA_DT_Month')) as 'three_months_ago_prev_year'`.

Is this the correct way to calculate the same, or am I missing anything?